# Are functions considered continuous at endpoints?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, definition

Consider a function $f(x)$ that has no jump, infinite, or removable discontinuities in the middle anywhere -- but maybe the domain is limited:

1. Would the endpoint $[a,$ be considered continuous?
2. What about the endpoint $(a,$?

I ask because I often see "a function is continuous if we can draw it without lifting up the pencil" but I didn't know to what extent this applies to the endpoints and whether or not it matters if the points themselves are defined.

Comment: And what is the domain of function?

Comment: I gave two examples, one ending in $[a$ and one ending in $(a$

Comment: If a does not belong to the domain of the function, then the function simply cannot be continuous at a

Comment: Let f(x)=sin(1/x).  Continuous at x=0?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I don't know... I guess "no"? $0$ isn't part of the function's domain right? $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is continuous **iff** it is continuous at each point of the domain,
so we need only consider points in the domain.

Hence, if the domain is of the form $(a,...$, the end point $a$ is of no concern
since it is not part of the domain. For example, $f(x) = {1 \over x}$ is
continuous on $(0,\infty)$. The point $0$ is not an issue since it is not part of
the domain.

If the domain has the form $[a,...$ then if $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ then
$f$ must have values close to $f(a)$ for $x$ close to $a$ (**and** in the domain). In particular, $f$ **must** be defined at $x=a$.

One characterization is for all sequences $x_n \to a$ (with $x_n $ in the domain)  we must have $f(x_n) \to f(a)$. This is equivalent to drawing the curve without lifting.

**Illustrations**:

The function $f(x) = -1 $ for $x \in [-1,0]$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in (1,2]$, with
domain $[-1,0] \cup (1,2]$ is continuous everywhere.

The function $f(x) = -1 $ for $x \in [-1,0]$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in (0,2]$, with
domain $[-1,2]$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.

The function that is $0$ everywhere except at $x=0$ where $f(0) = 1$ is
continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.

Comment: What about a function that is just a single point?

Comment: If the domain has a single point $a$, then the only sequence that converges to $a$ (and lies in the domain) is the sequence $a,a,a, ...$ so we see that the corresponding function values converge to $f(a)$ (in fact, they are **all** $f(a)$), so yes, the function is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Is it like saying the limit $L$ exists at $f(x)$ and not only that but $f(x) = L$ too?

Comment: @user525456: Yes, it says that the limit exists and is equal to $f$ evaluated at that point. Look at the third example in my answer.

Comment: So really "a function is continuous if we can draw the whole thing without lifting the pencil" does have some truth to it; the non-continuous stuff only applies when we have some kind of break/split in the middle of the function somewhere other than at the endpoints?

Comment: @user525456: Well, roughly yes. The catch is that the domain may not be connected (in a topological sense). So, in my first illustration above, you can draw the function without lifting the pencil on either of $[-1,0]$ and $(1,2]$, but you can't 'jump' from one to the other.

Comment: Interesting, then what's the difference then between a function that has a noncontinuous area in the middle and a function that is continuous on its domain because the domain is defined to have such a space in the middle but otherwise looks the same on paper? (I worded this badly, I hope you know what I mean)

Comment: Like why can't we just take any noncontinuous points/areas and redefine the domain to exclude them?

Comment: @user525456: Those functions would have different domains.

Comment: @user525456: You may end up with an empty domain. For example, the function that is $0$ on the rationals and $1$ otherwise is discontinuous everywhere. (Even though continuity is referred to as elementary, there are a lot of weird examples out there.)

Comment: Thank you. For the first illustration: What if it was $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in [1, 2]$? I guess it would still be a continuous function and we couldn't say it is discontinuous at $x=1$. Am I right?

Comment: @LarsSmith It would be continuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, you need a better definition of continuity than "a  function is continuous if we can draw it without lifting up the pencil."  The definition that is usually the first rigorous definition that students see is

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  A function $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $a\in D$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x\in D$ and $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$.

Here, the notation $f : D\to\mathbb{R}$ says that $f$ is a function with domain $D$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$ (the real numbers).  In other words, $f$ takes real numbers from some set $D$ as input, and outputs other real numbers.  The definition of the domain is quite important here, as it specifies what kinds of objects or numbers $f$ can work with.

Next, the definition of continuity basically says that you set an error tolerance $\varepsilon$, and always find a region around $a$ such that choosing any value of $x$ in that region ensures that the output will be within your error tolerance.

This definition says nothing about endpoints, and can be applied to such points as easily as any other, as long as they are in the domain of the function.  In particular, this means that if you define a function an an interval $[a,b]$, then it could be continuous at either $a$ or $b$.  On the other hand, if it is defined on $(a,b)$, then it cannot be continuous at either $a$ or $b$, as it is not defined there.

In either case, a function is continuous on its domain if it is continuous at every point in the domain.  Thus a function can be continuous on either $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$.  In the former case the function would necessarily be continuous at $a$ and $b$ (if it is continuous on its domain), and in the latter case $f$ would not be continuous at either $a$ or $b$ as it is not even defined there.

Comment: What is $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? A function that accepts reals and outputs reals?

Comment: This says that $f$ is a function with domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}$ (the real numbers).

Comment: But overall isn't the $(\epsilon, \delta)$ stuff more the definition for a two-sided limit, as opposed to the one-sided limits we might see at endpoints?

Comment: Nope.  For a one sided limit, you would need the additional hypothesis that $x<a$ or $x>a$.  For example, for the right-hand limit, we would have to find $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x\in D$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ *and* $x > a$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I'm confused now, since I thought you couldn't have two-sided limits at endpoints, but this definition in the answer appears to be for two-sided limits. But we still define a function as continuous on its domain even at endpoints if we have $[a, b]$ but not $(a, b)$?

Comment: The definition of limit given in my answer says nothing about the limit being one-sided or two-sided, and says nothing about one-sided or two-sided continuity.  Indeed, you don't need to distinguish between the two "types" of limits for working with endpoints, since both the one-sided and two-sided notions of continuity will agree.

Comment: Wow, this definition of continuity seems very weird. Are you sure it's correct? Because it allows functions like $f: \{\frac{1}{n}: n ∈ \mathbb{Z}^+\} \cup \{0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1$ to be continuous? There are like infinite "breaks" in the graph. The usual definition doesn't include $x \in D$ so that $f$ is defined "near" $a$. Thoughts?

Comment: @William That function is continuous on its domain.

Comment: Xander, isn't "continuity" for single real variable functions suppose to capture the idea that graph has no "breaks" or "holes". What is this definition trying to capture apart from the obvious fact that limit must be equal to the value of the function at the point? Is that it?

Comment: @William That is the intuition, yes.  But the function you have defined is not a function of a real variable.  It is a function of the set $D = 1/\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ (to abuse notation).  As far as that function is concerned, the only set which exists is $D$, and on that set, the function is continuous.  The "drawing a function without lifting the pen" is an nice, intuitive explanation of what continuity means, but it is only relevant or meaningful for functions defined on intervals.

Comment: I see the point you're trying to make but it's not a function of a real variable? Isn't $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @William There is a sloppiness of the English language all over this question.  When I said that your function was not a function of a real variable, my intended meaning was that the domain of your function is not $\mathbb{R}$ (nor any interval in $\mathbb{R}$---i.e. not a set on which the "usual" analysis makes sense), but only a very small subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  But this sloppiness of language is a red herring.  The function you have defined is continuous on its domain.  Its domain is not $\mathbb{R}$.